# Share nvraid ext3 raid 0 disk across network from Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, ext3

I have a dual boot setup between windows vista 64-bit and ubuntu (11 or 12--latest as of a month ago or so, I think). Ubuntu is installed on an nforce4 nvraid raid 0 disk. Windows is installed on a separate disk.

I want to boot into Windows, be able to browse all the files on my ubuntu install and share it across the network.

Basically, I'm setting up a new computer, converting this one to windows, but I need to access my ubuntu data.

I installed the nforce4 mediashield drivers, but I'm still not seeing that disk.

I tried ext2 IFS for windows but it won't mount it--it says to format it.

DiskInternals Linux Reader can read it, but I need to share it across the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just copying the files over to the windows drive using Linux Reader and then shared from there.